# Fusion Charts column2d showZeroPlane when it has only positive or negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery, fusioncharts

For **FusionChart - Column2d,**

If I have values as 0.1,0.2 and -1, then i m able to see zeroPlane
[image: With ZeroPlane]

If I have values as 0.1,0.2 and 1 (all positive values), then i m not able to see zeroPlane

[image]

I want to show zeroPlane irrespective of value

you can test these values at here -

```
jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/k9sRG/ 

{
  "showZeroPlane": "1",                                
  "zeroPlaneColor":"#003366",
  "zeroPlaneAlpha": "100",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following properties to your Json file.

```
 "yAxisMinValue" : "-1.0",
 "yAxisMaxValue" : "1.0"
```

To get zero plane if you're having only positive or negative values.

Comment: Thanx Nishant Sharma